# Chevalley property for Tannakian categories

Tags: tannakian-category, symmetric-monoidal-categories

Are all Tannakian categories have the Chevalley property? I know that the categories $\mathrm{Rep}_k(G)$ have the Chevalley property for affine algebraic groups $G$ over a field $k$, but I don't know the answer for non-neutral Tannakian categories.

(Chevalley property means that the tensor product of every two semisimple objects is semisimple.)

**Edit**. By zeno's comment, Chevalley property is not valid even for neutral Tannakian categories in positive characteristic. So let's add a further condition $\mathrm{char}(k)=0$ to above question.

Comment: Over a field of nonzero characteristic, it's not true that a tensor product of semisimple representations is necessarily semisimple. See, for example, Deligne, Pierre. Semi-simplicité de produits tensoriels en caractéristique $p$. (French) [Semisimplicity of tensor products in characteristic $p$] Invent. Math. 197 (2014), no. 3, 587--611. MR3251830

Comment: @zeno Thanks for the reference. I think the general case of Tannakian categories in characteristic $0$ can be proved using extension of the scalars to $\bar{k}$, which neutralize the category and using corollary 4.11 in Deligne's paper.